# Call a button_click on page_load asp.net

Tags: asp.net, pageload

I have a search textbox and a search button, when clicked displays a grid with the following names and gender.However I have redirected the page to another page on edit.Now When I comeback from that page to the page containing the gridview I want to display the same search again. I have successfully put retrieved the information but storing it into session, but I'm not able to call my btn_click event @ page_Load.

Here's a snippet:

**EDIT:** I have made some changes in my code

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   if (Session["Redirected"] != null)
    {
        if (Session["FirstName"] != null)
            txtSearch.Text = Session["FirstName"].ToString();
        if (Session["Gender"] != null)
            ddlGen.SelectedValue = Session["Gender"].ToString();
        btnSearch_Click(sender, e);
    }

    if (!Page.IsPostBack)
    {
        BindGrid();
    }
}
```

and here's the click event:

```
protected void btnSearch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string query = "Select EmployeeId,FirstName,Password,Address,sex,Deptno,act_book,actTV,DOJ,isActiveYN from employees where 1=1";

    if (txtSearch.Text != "")
    {
        query += " and FirstName like '%" + txtSearch.Text + "%'";
        Session["FirstName"] = txtSearch.Text;
    }
    if (ddlGen.SelectedValue != "")
    {
        query += "  and sex='" + ddlGen.SelectedValue.ToUpper() + "'";
        Session["Gender"] = ddlGen.SelectedValue;
    }


    DataSet ds = new DataSet("Employees");
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Password=admin;User ID=admin;Initial Catalog=asptest;Data Source=dbsvr");
    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(query, con);            


    da.Fill(ds);
    gvSession.DataSource = ds;
    gvSession.DataBind();


}
```

Now I'm able to save search, so that problem is resolved ,but another has poped up that when I click the button search after changin text it takes me back to the older search..The reason is probably because sessions are not cleared,but I did that as well by handling **textchanged** and **selectedindexchanged** eventd.

Comment: Be careful with that search text - it looks like it's vulnerable to SQL injection attacks, but also would fail if a user non-maliciously included an apostrophe.

Comment: I'm aware of it.I'll rectfy it,this is just test code.Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should reset the session redirected variable so it doesn't fall in the same case.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   if (Session["Redirected"] != null)
   {
        Session["Redirected"] = null;
        ....
```

Answer (score 2):

Rather than trying to call your button click handler from the `Page_Load`, change your button click handler to simply call another method like:

```
protected void btnSearch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     RunSearch();
}
```

Then move all your `btnSearch_Click()` code into `RunSearch()`

Then in your `Page_Load` you can do something like:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (Session["Gender"] != null && Session["FirstName"] != null)
    {
        txtSearch.Text = Session["FirstName"].ToString();
        ddlGen.SelectedValue = Session["Gender"].ToString();
        RunSearch();
    }

    if (!Page.IsPostBack)
    {
        BindGrid();

    }
}
```

---

On a side note, I would recommend taking a look into `SQLCommand Parameters`. Your code is prone to `SQL Injection Attacks`:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection

Answer (score 1):

You can do using an QueryString paremeter when page return back to main page then here you can check QueryString paremeter is exist. here you can implement code for bind grid

```
if (Request.QueryString["Back"]!= null)
{
    // Your bind grid function
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a function, which will called both from the button_click and page_load.